# If else statement in vue.js with value from json

Tags: javascript, if-statement, vue.js

I got value from json in table, and I need if else statement. 
If value == enabled - some code..
else - some code.

example:

```
<md-table-cell>
  <span v-if="{{row.status}} == 'enabled'">
    <span>ENABLED<md-icon class="md-raised">check_circle</md-icon></span>
  </span>
  <span v-else>
    <span>DISABLED <md-icon class="md-raised">cancel</md-icon></span>
  </span>
</md-table-cell>
```

So, I need something like that. Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `v-if="row.status == 'enabled'"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong - you are using mustaches into the `v-if` which is not allowed and your code is suposed to not work, because think about `v-if` as vanilla javascript where mustaches doesn't work.

```
<span v-if="row.status == 'enabled'">
```